# Segment registers and paragraph boundaries 8086

Tags: assembly, intel, processor, memory-segmentation

Does the segment registers hold the physical address that is used as a base address or because the segments can start only on a paragraph boundary, the segment register only hold the ordinal number of the that paragraph boundary and then when multiplied by 10H the final physical base address is formed and then the offset is added. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Segment registers work like you describe on the actual 8086 processor. The physical address of a memory operand is determined by multiplying the value in the relevant segment register by 16 and adding it to the effective address of the operand.

On modern Intel processors segmentation only works this way while in real mode and virtual 8086 mode. (Strictly speaking it only works as-if this was how virtual/physical addresses are calculated. In reality loading a segment register in real mode loads a hidden selector cache entry with the segment base, and the value in the cache is used when calculating the virtual/physical address. The selector cache exists to speed up segmentation in protected mode where segment registers are used as indexes into tables in memory.)